# Using a Ref as an mutable object to prevent rerender

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create a button which changes its icon every time a certain function runs, and I'm storing the current icon in a useRef in my app.
Inside the functions, I consoled the icons and the changes occur, but when I console my ref in the body of my functional component, it doesn't change
Can I get some help on that? React says the ref is a mutable object and I wanted to achieve this behavior without getting a rerender.

my function:

```js
        
        const btnRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);
+   6   let holderRef = useRef<IconType>(FiHeart);


        useEffect(() => {
>>  9     const handleClick = (e) => {
   10       e.preventDefault();                                                              
+  11                                                                                        
+  12       if (holderRef.current === FiHeart) {
+  13         holderRef.current = AiFillHeart;                                                      
+  14       } else {                                                                                
+  15         holderRef.current = FiHeart;                                                          
+  16       }
   17     };                                                                                        
   18                                                                                               
~  19     btnRef.current.addEventListener("click", handleClick);                                    
   20                                                                                               
   21     return () => {
~  22       btnRef.current.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);                               
   23     };                                                                                        
   24   }, []);
   25                                                                                               
+  26   console.log(holderRef.current);
```

Comment: basically, use an SVG. CSS can be set via JS to switch it's color. you never want to use an anchor in place of a button. they're 2 diffirent elements entirely. use an anchor only when you actually navigate to a URI. use a button for everything else.

Comment: Can you show me how I can do it? I can't figure it out :(. I've been trying a lot of things for  hours, and no success.